# White point in PlotStyle

Tags: plotting

I have the following plot:

```
Show[ListPlot[{{{0.7, 0.12}}, {{0.8, 0.2}}, {{0.5, 0.4}}}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize[0.03]}, {Blue,PointSize[0.03]},
{White, PointSize[0.03]}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0.3, 1}, {0, 3}}], 
Plot[1/(Pi x^2), {x, 0.3, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, 
PlotRange -> {{0.3, 1}, {0, 3}}], 
Plot[1 - 2 x, {x, 0.3, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, 
PlotRange -> {{0.3, 1}, {0, 3}}], AxesOrigin -> {0.3, 0}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

which looks like:

[image]

One of the points doesn't appear as its color is chosen to be white. How can I make its surrounding (circumference) black in order to become visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PlotMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) rather than [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html)

```
Show[
 ListPlot[
  {{{0.7, 0.12}}, {{0.8, 0.2}}, {{0.5, 0.4}}},
  PlotMarkers -> {Style[●, Blue, 20],
    Style[●, Blue, 20], Style[○, Black, 20]},
  PlotRange -> {{0.3, 1}, {0, 3}}],
 Plot[{1/(Pi x^2), 1 - 2 x}, {x, 0.3, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {{ColorData[97][1], Thick}}],
 AxesOrigin -> {0.3, 0},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]